# Autofac - Reuse injected service in component to satisfy other components

Tags: c#, autofac

Using Autofac, suppose I have a PersonRepository and an EventRepository class, which both depend on a IDataService service... I use both of the repository classes in an Mvc Controller action (for example - might as well be some MvvM WPF application) like

```
public class Mycontroller : controller
{
   public Mycontroller(PersonRepository personRepo, EventRepository eventRepo) {...}
   ...
   public ActionResult Index(){ ... I use the repository classes in here ...}
}
public class PersonRepository
{
   public PersonRepository(IDataService service){...}
}
public class EventRepository
{
   public PersonRepository(IDataService service){...}
}
```

I want to make sure, when using the repository classes and injecting them with a IDataService implementation, that both of the repository classes receive **the same instance** of the IDataService service...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the lifetime of the IDataService.

Do you want to keep reusing the same one over and over again? Then it's basically a singleton, and you must configure Autofac to treat it as one:

```
builder.RegisterType<IDataService>().As<MyDataService>().SingleInstance();
```

But if you're running in MVC and want to reuse the same instance only during the lifetime of the HTTP request, you configure Autofac like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<IDataService>().As<MyDataService>().HttpRequestScoped();
```

Comment: The MVC sample is basically the solution I want. However, i'm wondering myself what the solution would be, considering I don't have a HTTP request. (for example in a MvvM WPF app)

Comment: In a WPF app it would be Singleton.

Comment: Not exactly. With a singleton I'd have one instance for the whole application, and not one unit of work... no?

Comment: Nowhere is it mentioned above that IDataService is a unit of work. It also doesn't sound like a unit of work, it sounds like a service. Your service would be a singleton, your unit of work would be managed on the service level -- that is, every C/U/D operation would create a unit of work.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Thanks for your help so far. Perhaps my fictional example wasn't the best choice hehe :) Seems the unit of work is indeed what i intended. But how do you do it, given the wish I want to avoid Autofac code inside the service? (http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/ explains unit of work with autofac with the help of the lifetime scope, but the code is mangled with .Resolve<>() calls. I'd like to do it purely with injection)

Comment: You can abstract the Resolve<>() calls away in a Helper class. Otherwise you can use constructor injection, if the objects you construct have shorter lifetimes than the objects being injected.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `.SingleInstance()` method when registering the component.  (assuming fluent registration)

Comment: SingleInstance will essentially create a singleton registration. What if one wants to selectively pass one instance of a service to one set of consumers, and another instance to another set of consumers based on some logic?

Comment: Then you would implement a Factory.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the [IComponentLifetime](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#15-NfL2P5pY/trunk/src/Source/Autofac/Core/IComponentLifetime.cs&q=IComponentLifetime&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) with your rules of reusing and register the services using your lifetime.

Comment: The lifetimescope is the closest I've gotten indeed. But in all the samples (ex. http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal), it seems your code is then mangled with specific Autofac code ( .Resolve() calls). Isn't it the goal of the whole IoC thing, to de-couple everything? (and thus, not to have any specific Autofac calls in your code, but to have everything injected)